# missing : after property id

Tags: javascript, jquery, galleria

Why does the following code cause Firebug to report an error on the line `$('#galleria').galleria({` ?

```
      $('#galleria').galleria({
              dataSource: data,
              width:930,
              height:575,
              transition: 'fade',
              carousel: 'true' ,
              carouselSpeed: 1200  ,
              showCounter :'false',
              showImagenav : 'false',
              showInfo : 'false',
              imageCrop : 'true',
              maxScaleRatio: 1,


              extend: function() {
                this.bind(Galleria.LOADFINISH, function(e) {
                 $(e.imageTarget).css('cursor','pointer').click(this.proxy(function(e) {
                   e.preventDefault(); // removes the garbage
                   $.fancybox({

                        $('#galleria').galleria({ 
                            width: 500,
                            height: 500
                        });        

                   });
                }))
               });
              }       
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.fancybox({

        $('#galleria').galleria({ 
            width: 500,
            height: 500
        });        

   });
```

is syntactically invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but are you missing a `;` after `}))`?

Like this:

```
       $(e.imageTarget).css('cursor','pointer').click(this.proxy(function(e) {
               e.preventDefault(); // removes the garbage
               $.fancybox({

                    $('#galleria').galleria({ 
                        width: 500,
                        height: 500
                    });        

               });
            })); //here
```